# My.Setting variable not reset after making exe

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-interface, settings, application-settings

I am making my application as exe file..
 In my project i am using setting variable to count the number of times the applications opened.. if the user opens the application more than 5 times i want to restrict the user from opening the application again. for that i am using the following coding in form shown

```
        Private Sub T01SaleBill_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, _ 
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
                 if my.settings.openedtimes >5 then
                 me.close()
                 else
                 my.settings.openedtimes += 1;
                 my.settings.save()
                end if;

     End Sub
```

the exe file created and it works fine through my exe..after the application opened 5 times.. the form closed.. now i reset the my.settings.openedtimes as 0 and again create a new exe. now i uninstall previous exe.. and run the new exe. this times also my form closed. i think the setting variable my.settings.openedtimes holds value greater than 5 as previous. i can't understand what is the problem with this settings variable.. can anyone help me what's the problem here..

Comment: Did you remove the settings file from the relevent user profile directory?

Comment: @RowlandShaw setting file means? i removed the applications folder from the exe installed path.. not seperately the setting file.

Comment: Rowland is right it will leave the user config behind unless you create something to clean it out as part of your uninstall process.

Comment: @jcwrequests how to clean the settings after uninstall the application. where will be the settings file in my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean setting named newvers and set it to true in the settings designer.  Then try this

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, _
                        e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    If My.Settings.newvers Then
        My.Settings.Upgrade() 'get previous values
        'change values that should not be carried over
        My.Settings.openedtimes = 1
        My.Settings.newvers = False 'turn new version off
    Else
        My.Settings.openedtimes += 1
    End If
    If My.Settings.openedtimes > 5 Then Me.Close()
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: your answer shows that my.settings.openedtimes always 1..may i know when will it increment.you set newvers as true.and don't change it any situation..so else part don't perform